# Looking for more info on Lithium Ion battery

Tags: lithium-ion, circuit-protection

My University Makerspace has these Lithium Ion batteries but I only have the information printed on the battery itself which follows :

`PSEBATTERY                   +
H535585   3100mAh
11.47Wh  HC  11L29           -`

With this information, is there a way to tell what voltage it outputs? 
(I'm pretty sure it is 3.7V but I rather have it confirmed by someone who knows their stuff...)
Finally, it has a red, yellow and black wire. I assume the red is the positive terminal and black negative but I am unsure if the yellow is the thermal information as well as to how I can use that information to my advantage.

Thank you!

Comment: Batteries produce DC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it says 3.1Ah and 11.47Wh, then 11.47/3.1 = 3.7V, so you are right. But how you can possibly ask if it is AC or DC, is beyond me.

Given the common color coding practice, your guess about red and black wires is likely correct. Your guess can be backed up with a measurement of voltage when applying a modest load, say, 100 Ohm resistor between red and black.

The middle wire is likely the terminal for thermal resistor. You can try to check its impedance by measuring it with Ohmmeter, between yellow and black. But first use Voltmeter to check if there is no voltage. The resistance will be likely about 10k, or might be higher, 22-56k.